# How to find record in asp.net mvc (without id)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

How can I find record without id?

This doesn't work

```
Wallet wallet = db.Wallet.Where(n => n.Name == My.Name && n.UserId == userId);
```

This works fine

```
Wallet wallet = db.Wallet.Find();
```

Comment: Its been a while since i've looked at this, but if you are returning only one result use FirstOrDefault in place of Where.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" you need to explain why it doesn't work. Does it give a compilation error? What's the error? Have you tried searching for that error to see what others have done?

Comment: @TinMan7757 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq queries can return multiple results, and you can't assign an `IEnumerable<Wallet>` when you've only allocated space for a single `Wallet`. If you only want one result, you should use an appropriate method to narrow it down.

- [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx)

  > Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.
- [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx).

  > Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.
- [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx)

  > Returns the first element of a sequence.
- [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx)

  > Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

As an example:

```
Wallet wallet = db.Wallet.Where(n => n.Name == My.Name && n.UserId == userId).Single();
```

Always compare the return type of your Linq query to what you're trying to assign it to. Intellisense in Visual Studio will help you with that.

Note these methods all have overloads that make the use of "Where" unnecessary, you can put the filter lambda directly in the call, as in:

```
Wallet wallet = db.Wallet.Single(n => n.Name == My.Name && n.UserId == userId);
```

Which style you use is up to you, based on which you think is more readable. The performance difference is probably negligible (though it might be worth it to test).